# C# Linq to SQL vs Entity Framework .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, .net-core

I decided to start learning something about .Net Core and Entity Framework for Core. Since most of our apps rely heavily on data access, I decided to start with the Entity Framework for .Net Core. After creating a working app, I decided to run the same the same query using Linq to SQL and test the response time. The database was local (running on the same machine). The EF code was created based on the following article… Data Points - Run EF Core on Both .NET Framework and .NET Core
(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt742867.aspx).

Linq to Sql vs Entity Famework Core – Speed Test

Linq to SQL in .net Library and called from .Net Console App
Entity Framework Core in a Core Library called same .Net Console App

The query transfers table fields to a DTO object

Records in Table: 1,906,643; Records returned in Query: 78; Linq to SQL: 3 Seconds; Entity Framework Core: 19 Seconds

Similar Query for Both Linq to SQL and EF Core…

```
public IEnumerable<PackageDataDTO> GetAll(string Building, string Status="All")
{
    using (var context = new PackageDataEF.PackageDataContext(_options))
    {
        var Lst = from Dbo in context.PackageData
                  where Dbo.BuildingNumber.Equals(Building)
                  && (Dbo.Status.Equals("All") || Dbo.Status.Equals(Status))
                  select new PackageDataDTO
                  {
                      RecordGuid = Dbo.RecordGuid,
                      //TimeStamp = Dbo.TimeStamp,
                      BuildingNumber = Dbo.BuildingNumber,
                      UnitNumber = Dbo.UnitNumber,
                      TrackingNumber = Dbo.TrackingNumber,
                      Carrier = Dbo.Carrier,
                      PackageType = Dbo.PackageType,
                      PackageLocation = Dbo.PackageLocation,
                      StorageArea = Dbo.StorageArea,
                      DateOfReceiptUTC = Dbo.DateOfReceiptUTC,
                      DateLastChangeUTC = Dbo.DateLastChangeUTC,
                      Status = Dbo.Status,
                      ResidentId = Dbo.ResidentId,
                      NotificationBy = Dbo.NotificationBy,
                      CallSid = Dbo.CallSid,
                      Comments = Dbo.Comments,
                      DeliveredTo = Dbo.DeliveredTo,
                      DeliveredBy = Dbo.DeliveredBy,
                      DeliveryNotes = Dbo.DeliveryNotes,
                      DeliveryConfirmation = Dbo.DeliveryConfirmation,
                      DelayedNotification = Dbo.DelayedNotification,
                      GroupedNotification = Dbo.GroupedNotification,
                      ButtonOnReceipt = Dbo.ButtonOnReceipt,
                  };
        return Lst.ToList();
    }
}
```

Is there really that much of a speed difference or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: How does the executed SQL compare? in some cases EF Core pulls too much data and does client evaluation - what EF Core version?

Comment: In EF Core run `.ToList()` first then map it to DTO objects

Comment: ErikEJ... Version is 1.1.1.0
Fabio... Will give that a try

Comment: Fabio... used per your instructions... same 19 seconds

Comment: First query to EF will take some time to setup some things like model. What happens the second time or third time if you execute the query three times in a row?

Comment: @Peter Bons I did a series of 4 queries. The first remained at 19 seconds and the following 3 had to be measured in milliseconds. Any suggestions on how to improve the time on the initial query? In real life, the code would be used in a web enviornment.

Comment: It's not clear if it's EF Core issue or db query execution (plan) issue. Can you measure the time of just executing the query, e.g. the time of `Lst.AsEnumerable().Any()` in EF Core?

Comment: @Ivan Stoev ... Everything executes in milliseconds until .ToList() which adds 22.8 seconds for a total of the 23 seconds.The slowdown appears to be in .ToList()

Comment: My point was that `ToList` does two things: (1) executes the query and then (2) processes the result set by reading each record, loading it in a class and add it to the list. The test I suggested was to measure the time of just the part (1). There is nothing essential to execute in your original code before `ToList` call.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev  ... Part (1) executes in milliseconds as does the query. The time is lost on .ToList() - 3 subsequent calls using the same query executes in total in a about 1.5 seconds including the .ToList() function. It is only teh initial call taht has the time issue.

Comment: I see. Then probably you need to post it to their issue tracker, the query is quite simple in order to be able to improve it in any way programmatically.

Comment: I kept playing around and changed the query to use .FromSql("Query").ToList() using a true SQL query and cut the time to about 2.9 seconds. Still trying to figure out why the Linq query .ToList() is still in the 20 second range.

Comment: For performance-critical queries consider using micro-ORM solutions like Dapper or NReco.Data, they perform result mapping much faster than EF Core.

Comment: @Gfw, any update or conclusion on this?

Comment: @clairestreb... no real change. It has gotten better with EF 2, but the initial call  still appears to be slow.